# application consumed by facebook while login via graph api

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, callback, facebook-login

While trying to login to my app if user click on create new account button on facebook login dialog user is not able to go back to application and consumed by facebook.

If there is any way or any callback for android please suggest.

LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

```
            mCurrentAccessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
            requestProfileInfo(new FacebookResult() {
                @Override
                public void postResult(FacebookProfileResponse result) {

                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

            mRequestStatus = REQUEST_STATUS_NO_REQUEST;
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {

            mRequestStatus = REQUEST_STATUS_NO_REQUEST;
        }
    });

    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(activity, getPermissions());

}
```

Comment: can you share your code?

Answer (score 0):

If you are launching another app from your app then there is no way to come back from that app except user comes back.

Except, if you are using O-Auth 2 and launching externel web browser for facebook login then you can come back through implementing deep linking into your app.

Comment: i am just using callback provided by facebook in graph api which shows login window

Comment: @virtual6 In that case you may have done something wrong implementing facebook login as facebook sdk for android just open webview for logging in. and in that case you can't come back if there is mistake in your implementation of facebook login.

Comment: yes in that dialog there is option for new user to sign up for facebook. if user clicks on that it lost application context.

Comment: @virtual6 please follow [facebook's official documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android) for implementing that or you may refer [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/) or [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_facebook_integration.htm). These are some good tutorials i have gone through.

Comment: is there any way i can know user clicked on login button or any other i.e. forgot password or create new user

Comment: @virtual6 No it's completely handled by facebook sdk